# Where does the "item" object come from in javaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Messing with some javaScript, I found that the variable name "item" was already being assigned before I declared it or assigned anything to it.  Tracing it backwards, I found that it even seemed defined before I did ANYTHING in js.  To verify this, I even put

```
<script>alert(item);</script>
```

on a line by itself IMMEDIATELY after opening the HEAD tag - upon loading the page, I get an alert box with the following:

```
"[object]"
```

If I do the same thing in FF, I get an error, saying that "item" is not defined.

Where is "item" coming from in IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out >> ["item" is a reserved keyword in IE](http://www.springenwerk.com/2009/01/is-reserved-word-in-internet-explorer-6.html)